# getting a JS file() through axios and firebase

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am trying to get a uploaded photo from Firebase using Axios and transform it into an File() object. I uploaded this photo in an other part of my app and saved a url to it in a registration. Now I am trying to get the file back from storage using the url. Problem is, it needs to be an File() object. I know how I can use the url to just display the image but that is not the goal.

This is my request:

```
fileFromURL(url, filename) {
  const imageFile = new File([''], 'filename');
  const config = {
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': imageFile.type,
    },
  };
  this.$axios.get(url, config)
    .then((response) => {
      // Here I am trying to transform the response to an File() object.

      const byteString = btoa(response.data);
      const ab = new ArrayBuffer(byteString.length);
      const ia = new Uint8Array(ab);
      for (let i = 0; i < byteString.length; i += 1) {
        ia[i] = byteString.charCodeAt(i);
      }
      const blob = new Blob([ia], { type: 'image/jpeg' });
      const file = new File([blob], filename);
    })
    .catch(() => {
      this.$q.notify({
        color: 'negative',
        position: 'top',
        message: 'Loading failed',
        icon: 'report_problem',
      });
    });
},
```

These are the response headers:

```
accept-ranges: bytes
access-control-expose-headers: Content-Length, Date, Server, Transfer-Encoding, X-GUploader-UploadID, X-Google-Trace
alt-svc: quic=":443"; ma=2592000; v="44,43,39"
cache-control: private, max-age=0
content-disposition: inline; filename*=utf-8''avatar.jpg
content-length: 1740563
content-type: image/jpeg
date: Mon, 04 Mar 2019 16:43:31 GMT
expires: Mon, 04 Mar 2019 16:43:31 GMT
last-modified: Wed, 27 Feb 2019 17:27:52 GMT
server: UploadServer
status: 200
```

and this is part of the response:

```
{data: "�PNG
↵↵
IHDR�x�� IDATx���w�%E�…���������������������������� �(�%�5IIEND�B`�", status: 200, statusText: "", headers: {…}, config: {…}, …}
config: {adapter: ƒ, transformRequest: {…}, transformResponse: {…}, timeout: 0, xsrfCookieName: "XSRF-TOKEN", …}
data: "�PNG
↵↵
IHDR�x�� IDATx���w�%E�"
headers: {date: "Mon, 04 Mar 2019 16:43:31 GMT", x-guploader-uploadid: "AEnB2UqVnwrANAK9hLdD6vQZA_HAIIzgmMz1EA5foN16jLnfuBcNSB0TIFr4C59I3cA4CRhnN2UloR5tdBK4UQ5IDihbpelJRQ", content-length: "16965", last-modified: "Wed, 27 Feb 2019 17:27:32 GMT", server: "UploadServer", …}
request: XMLHttpRequest {onreadystatechange: ƒ, readyState: 4, timeout: 0, withCredentials: false, upload: XMLHttpRequestUpload, …}
status: 200
statusText: ""
__proto__: Object
```

As you can see the data is filled with a long string (16246 characters).

So how can I change this into a File() object?

Comment: What is the goal then?

Comment: The goal is to have a File object that I can feed into an plugin that only takes file objects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can configure axios to return the response as a `Blob` directly, so you don't have to convert it yourself with:

`responseType: 'blob'`

```
fileFromURL(url, filename) {
  // *removed quotes from filename, typo I guess?
  const imageFile = new File([''], filename);
  const config = {
    // *removed headers as we don't know the file type anyway, I guess?
    responseType: 'blob'
  };
  this.$axios.get(url, config)
    .then((response) => {
      const file = new File([response.data], filename);
  });
}
```

Demo: 
[image: Edit Vue Template]

Comment: Yes, this is the solution. Thank you.